# Why do I need to create a file on disk to get a full size image taken by the camera

Tags: android, image, camera, android-permissions

I'm working with the camera in Android for the first time and am hung up on a few things that seem to be required.  I've given the app Camera permissions and I can see the thumbnail image.

After searching I found [this google example](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html) that states I must create a file to see the full size image.  Why? Also, in creating a file I have to ask the user for permission to write to disk.  I have no intention of saving the photos, however I need to create a file and and now need to worry about file cleanup.

Lastly, this full sized image has no EXIF data.  I've found a way to create a bitmap with the file to rotate the image.  Is this correct?  It seems like a lot of work to just see a correctly oriented image that i've just taken.

Answer (score 3):

> After searching I found this google example that states I must create a file to see the full size image. Why?

A full-size photo is much larger than the 1MB limit for `Intent` contents.

> I have no intention of saving the photos, however I need to create a file and and now need to worry about file cleanup.

Then do not use `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`. Use the camera APIs directly (`android.hardware.Camera`, `android.hardware.camera2.*`) or via a third-party wrapper (Fotoapparat, CameraKit-Android).

> this full sized image has no EXIF data

With `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`, you are delegating to whatever camera app the user happens to choose. That will be one of hundreds of camera apps, whether pre-installed on the user's chosen device or installed by the user from the Play Store or elsewhere. The behavior of those camera apps, with respect to EXIF tags and anything else, is up to the developers of those camera apps.

It is also possible that you are not reading the EXIF tags correctly.

Answer (score 0):

> After searching I found this google example that states I must create a file to see the full size image.

That is a nonsense statement in that document. You do not have to create a file yourself. You only need to supply a file path in the intent so the used Camera app knows where to store the image.

Further i never saw a camera app that didnot include an exif header.